# Nginx Controller Returns 404 Not Found On Path and Default Backend

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have created a kubernetes cluster using Vagrant. I created a Nginx pod and a Cluster IP service for it. I can curl both the pod and the service getting a successful result. I have now installed an Nginx Ingress Controller from: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal-clusters and ran the following command:
`kubectl create ingress nginxingress --rule="/nginx=nginx-service:80" --annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target=/ --default-backend=nginx-service:80` and they both have been setup correctly as far as I see as there are no errors. But whenever I try to curl the path then it fails, the controller keeps throwing a 404 Not found.
Some more information that might help:
**services**:
[image]
**ingresses**:
[image]
any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: how you are curling the service of Nginx ? there is no external IP for service Nginx. Also please try to add the ingress class in your config

Comment: hi @HarshManvar i go: curl <machineIP>:NodePort/nginx. The nodeport being that of the controller service. what do you mean an ingress class? isnt that only necessary for pathTypes of ImplementationSpecific?

Comment: ingress class is the one which binds ingress and ingress controller together it's kind of connection which one you want to use. there could be multiple ingress controller running in single cluster so ingress is key point

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the ingress class annotation to the ingress configuration. `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

use below YAML as reference and try to update the configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myserviceb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myserviceb.foo.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: adding the class worked. thanks man. such a simple problem

Comment: how do i see the name for the controller that i needs name to put in the ingress class field?

Comment: By default it will be nginx for Nginx for others you can search or set manually. You can also set own class name in ingress Nginx contrôller by passing argument or updating controller config.

Comment: ah ok cool. i see the nginx controller creates a Ingress Class called nginx

Comment: This also worked for me but why? Any resource to explain this answer?

Comment: Ingress class connect all jngress resources to controller that you are running like nginx controller, Apache controller or any other. So if ingress is not connected to controller consider it like throw 404 error or not work properly

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but was already using `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` as in Harsh Manvar answer.

If you need to match multiple URLs and not only the basic host URL like me, on your ingress use:

1. `spec.rules.[your-host].path: "/(.*)"`
2. `spec.rules.[your-host].path: Prefix`
3. metadata.annotations.`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"`

More detail about this config [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)

OBS: some times update a ingress dosent work, you may need to delete and recreate the ingress.